# How do I refresh the page on click if an element has exact text?

Tags: jquery

I have a link that says 'Add to Favorites'. By default when you click this link and you are logged in, you get diverted to a confirmation page to say your favorite has been added. If you are not logged in it takes you to a login screen.

If you have already added that item to your favorites the text says 'Remove from Favorites' with an updated link to include '?A=Remove'. If you click it, you are redirected to a page confirming the favorite removal.

Now what I want to do is this:

If you're not logged in get an alert message.

If you are logged in - Refresh the page (Ideally I'd like to change 'Add to favorites' to 'Favorite added successfully' instead of refreshing the page - but I don't know how).

If you have already added to the favorites - Refresh the page (Ideally I'd like to change 'Remove from Favorites' to 'Favorite removed successfully' instead of refreshing the page - but I don't know how).

The {module_isloggedin} tag is generated by the system I am using. It generates a '1' if logged in & '0' if not logged in.

So far all that happens is the error message - Perhaps because my :contains isn't working?

The whole code seems much too long and sloppy. I'm still learning :)

This is my jQuery so far, I haven't put in a page refresh for the 'remove from favorites' yet.

/** Updated code works, just a bit ugly :) **/

```
jQuery('.add-favourites a').live('click', function(e){   
                    e.preventDefault();

        var loggedin = "{module_isloggedin}";

        if  (loggedin == 1) {
            var stringtocheckon = jQuery('.add-favourites a').html();

            if(stringtocheckon.indexOf('Add to Favorites')>=0) {
                $.ajax({
                        url: $(this).attr('href'),
                        data: { 'A': 'Add' },
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            document.location.reload(true);
                        }
                    });

            }else{
                if(jQuery(this).attr('href').indexOf("A=Remove") != -1){
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: jQuery(this).attr('href'),
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            document.location.reload(true);
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: jQuery(this).attr('href')+"&A=Remove",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            document.location.reload(true);
                        }
                    });
                }
    }
    }else{
        alert('You must be logged in to add favourites.');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Jquery library, to get the value ( string , text or other html ) from inside an element we can use .html() or .text();

```
var stringtocheckon = $('.box-content ul li').html();
```

then check

```
if(stringtocheckon.indexOf('Add to Favorites')>=0) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     $('.add-favourites a').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var obj = $(this);

                //var loggedin = "{module_isloggedin}";
                var loggedin = "1";

                if (loggedin == 1) {
                    if ($(this).hasClass('AddToFavourites')) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: $(this).attr('href'),
                            data: { 'A': 'Add' },
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (data) {
                                obj.removeClass('AddToFavourites').addClass('RemoveFromFavourites').text('Favorite added successfully');
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: $(this).attr('href'),
                            data: { 'A': 'Remove' },
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (data) {
                                obj.removeClass('RemoveFromFavourites').addClass('AddToFavourites').text('Add to favorites');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    alert('You must be logged in to add favorites.');
                }
            });


<a href="Your Url" class="AddToFavourites">Add to favorites</a>
<a href="Your Url" class="RemoveFromFavourites">Favorite added successfully</a>
```

Comment: jqyery what version u r using?

Comment: this code will not refresh u page offten if the user click Add to favorites or Favorite added successfully.. add class for 'Add to favorites' that will be usefull..

Comment: Thanks ThulasiRam, your success string inside the .ajax helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You're welcome Justin,

You say the code is a bit ugly - to tidy, create yourself a function to do the ajax bit ...

```
function getmypageandreload(url,senddata) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: { 'A': senddata },
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
    document.location.reload(true);
  }
}

 $(".yourelementclass").click(function() {

  var loggedin = "{module_isloggedin}";
  var url=$(this).attr('href');
  var senddata="";

   if (loggedin == 1) {
var stringtocheckon = $('.add-favourites a').html();
      if(stringtocheckon.indexOf('Add to Favorites')>=0) {
         senddata="Add";
      } else if($(this).attr('href').indexOf("A=Remove") != -1){    
         senddata = "Remove"; 
      }

    getmypageandreload(url,senddata);


    } else { alert('You must be logged in to add favourites.');  }
  });

 });
```

It looks like you can further cut down on the 'if else's; by setting a default of senddata = "remove" here too . It looks like it is only ever add or remove that you are using.

I have not run the above code but hope you get the gist

Rob